# Volterra Integral equation with a solution as a finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, integral-equations

There is an integral equation

$$
y(x)=\cos(\rho x) + \int_a^xq(t)y(t-a)\frac{\sin(\rho(x-t))}{\rho}dt
$$

The solution of it could be represented in the form

$$
y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty y_k
$$

and there is a recursive expression

$$
y_0(x) = \cos(\rho x)
$$
$$
y_{k+1}(x)=\int_a^xq(t)y_k(t-a)\frac{\sin(\rho(x-t))}{\rho}dt
$$

How is it possible to prove that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty y_k$ has only a finite number of non-zero elements?

Comment: Do you have any additional information about $q(t)$? Since $y_K \equiv 0  \implies  y_k \equiv 0 \;\; \forall k \geq K$, I would expect that to be a good avenue to try, but without any information on $q(t)$, that seems fruitless.